# avoid awk conditionals on certain fields

Tags: awk, scripting

I have `"|"` delimited file, with fields that represent:

```
firstname|secondname|Kernel|Version|Year
```

For example:

```
Linus|Torvald|VMLINUZ||1994
Jochen|Liedtke|L4|||
Apple||Darwin||2000
```

I want `"\t"` delimited results, with few conditionals.
If any column is empty, it'll substitute with `"-"`, but it gets complex in few cases, where any of first or second name is empty. I don't want it to happen.

Simply, concatenate first & second name, but if any of these columns empty, don't replace with `"-"` otherwise this condition applies on other empty fields.

I wrote following awk script, but it replaces empty first or second name with `"-"` too.

```
BEGIN {
FS="|";
OFS="\t"
}
{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) sub(/^$/, "-", $i) }
{
print $5, $4, $2" "$1
}
```

It gives this output:

```
1994    -   Torvald Linus
-   -   Liedtke Jochen
2000    -   - Apple
```

so the last line should be

```
2000    -   Apple
```

Final Output

```
1994    -   Torvald Linus
-   -   Liedtke Jochen
2000    -   Apple
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="\t" }
{
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i == "") {
            $i = "-"
        }
    }
    print $5, $4, ($2=="" ? "" : $2 " ") $1
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1994    -       Torvald Linus
-       -       Liedtke Jochen
2000    -       Apple
```